# Random split list, keeping the original order in new lists

Tags: python

I am having a hard time formulating my question so I'll just show by example.

```
x = ['abc', 'c', 'w', 't', '3']
a, b = random_split(x, 3)      # first list should be length 3
# e.g. a => ['abc', 'w', 't']
# e.g. b => ['c', '3']
```

Is there an easy way of splitting a list into two random samples while maintaining the original ordering?

---

**Edit:** I know that I could use random.sample and then reorder, but I was hoping for an easy, simple, one line method.

**Edit 2:** Here's another solution, see if you can improve it:

```
def random_split(l, a_size):
    a, b = [], []
    m = len(l)
    which = ([a] * a_size) + ([b] * (m - a_size)) 
    random.shuffle(which)

    for array, sample in zip(which, l):
        array.append(sample)

    return a, b
```

**Edit 3:** My concern in avoiding sorting was that in the best case scenario it is `O(N*log(N))`. It should be possible to get a function that scales `O(N)` Unfortunately, none of the solutions posted so far actually achieve `O(N)` Though, after a little thought I found one that works and is comparable to @PedroWerneck's answer in performance. Though, I'm not 100% sure that is truly random.

```
def random_split(items, size):
  n = len(items)
  a, b = [], []
  for item in items:
    if size > 0 and random.random() < float(size)/n:
      b.append(item)
      size -= 1
    else:
      a.append(item)

    n -= 1

  return a, b
```

Comment: I barely have any python experience, but how about this: generate a random number between 0 and the list size and then split on that index.

Comment: @Jasper That doesn't work because as you can see some items in b come before a.

Comment: random.sample does preserve sample order. It would be pretty simple to take random samples and then do a set difference. You could subclass ordereddict and create an ordered set...

Comment: @JoelCornett `random.sample` doesn't preserve order, it might have before, but it doesn't anymore. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample): `The resulting list is in selection order so that all sub-slices will also be valid random samples`

Comment: @JoelCornett though the funny thing is, from the docs it looks like random.sample used to do exactly what I want.

Comment: Are the values in list going to be unique? Or are duplicates a possibility?

Comment: ideally they're not unique, but in this case they are.

Comment: @JacobEggers: hehe. From which python version?

Comment: Your proposed solution in the second edit is really clever. But I think hexparrot's answer is best (if you replace the `list` of indices with a `set`).

Comment: You are mistaken in believing that none achieve O(n). Several of these do!! Most notably your own second edit is O(n).

Comment: @senderle good catch on the half of size. I made some code clarification and created a couple of bugs. It's fixed now. The distribution looks random now too. http://codepad.org/1IT27rRB

Comment: @senderle Hmm. I assumed shuffle would be the same as sorting, I forgot about the Fisher-Yates shuffle. I guess it depends on how the random module implements shuffle. I had run some tests and thought I saw the implementations all scaling as `O(n*log(n))` When I get home, I'll double check.

Comment: Shuffle is definitely O(n). The shuffle algorithm implemented in [`random`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py#l276) is identical to that described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm). [`random.sample`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py#l290) is also O(n); it selects a random number from the first `n` values of a `pool`, appends it to the list, swaps the chosen value with the value at `n`, and then decrements `n`.

Comment: The current third edit _may_ produce a reasonably uniform distribution. I did a bunch of ad-hoc statistical tests, all of which it passed. Still, I prefer the certainty provided by a `shuffle`- or `sample`-based solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's impossible to do the limiting and no sorting after splitting while keeping the randomness in a simpler way than just sampling and reordering.

If there was no limit, it would be as random as the RNG can by by iterating over the list, and choosing randomly which destination list to send the values to:

```
>>> import random
>>> x = range(20)
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> for v in x:
...     random.choice((a, b)).append(v)
... 
>>> a
[0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 12, 15, 17]
>>> b
[1, 5, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 16, 18, 19]
```

If you can deal with some bias, you can stop appending to the first list when it reaches the limit and still use the solution above. If you'll deal with small lists like in your example, it shouldn't be a big deal to retry it until you get the first list length right.

If you want it to be really random and be able to limit the first list size, then you'll have to give up and reorder at least one of the lists. The closest to a one liner implementation I can think is something like:

```
>>> x = range(20)
>>> b = x[:]
>>> a = sorted([b.pop(b.index(random.choice(b))) for n in xrange(limit)])
>>> a
[0, 1, 5, 10, 15, 16, 17]
>>> b
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 18, 19]
```

You have to sort a, but b has the order kept.

**edit**

Now, do you really have to avoid reordering at all costs? Many neat solutions were posted, and your second solution is very nice, but none of them is simpler, easier and shorter than:

```
def random_split(items, size):
    sample = set(random.sample(items, size))
    return sorted(sample), sorted(set(items) - sample)
```

Even considering both sorting operations, I think it's hard to beat that one for simplicity and efficiency. Consider how optimized Python's Timsort is and how most other methods have to iterate over the n items at least once for each list.

If you really must avoid reordering, I guess this one also works and is very easy and simple, but iterates twice:

```
def random_split(items, size):
    sample = set(random.sample(items, size))
    a = [x for x in items if x in sample]
    b = [x for x in items if x not in sample]
    return a, b
```

This is essentially the same as Hexparrot's solution with the set(sample) suggested by senderle to make comparisons O(1), and removing the redundant index sample and enumerate calls. You don't need that if you deal only with hashable objects.

Comment: Don't forget the second parameter to `random_split`

Comment: Ops... that makes it a lot more complicate. It will be hard to find anything simpler than the sample, diff and reorder method. Limiting size on iteration will cause the non-limited list to get the highest values more often.

Comment: Hexparrot's method does two n*n search for the items after sampling, based on the ordered list, which is effectively sorting the sample, in a much more expensive way than sorted(sample()) would be. So, that method is not only doing exactly what the OP isn't willing to do, but doing it in the most expensive way.

Comment: And I didn't said I believe it's impossible to do. I said I believe it's impossible to limit one of the samples while keeping the order and doing no further sorting without losing randomness. The solution given by the OP on his edit2 is the closest to it, which is essentially the same as the first solution I proposed, but I'm not sure it doesn't reduce randomness.

Comment: @pjwerneck, you're mistaken. The OP's edit2 is totally different from your first solution, and it accomplishes exactly what you say you believe is impossible. It randomly partitions the list into two lists of size `n` and `len(x) - n` every time, in a uniformly random way, maintaining the original order, without sorting.

Comment: It's not totally different, is essentially the same, limiting how many times each list can get chosen.

Comment: Nice edit, +1 -- note that removing `enumerate` only works if the items are hashable.

Answer (score 4):

How about this approach.  Random sample from the indexes and return two lists from two list comprehensions *if in* and *if not in*:

```
def random_split(lst, size):
    import random
    samp = set(random.sample(xrange(len(lst)),size))
    return ([v for i,v in enumerate(lst) if i in samp],
            [v for i,v in enumerate(lst) if i not in samp])

x = ['abc', 'c', 'w', 't', '3']

print random_split(x,3)
```

returns

```
(['abc', 't', '3'], ['c', 'w']) #random and retains order
```

Comment: It's a nice way to do it, but the n*n searches for the membership checks make it a lot worse than the sample-reorder approach.

Comment: +1; but change `samp` to a set to avoid the O(n) overhead of a linear search.

Comment: Since the list comprehension is ordered, there's no real need to iterate over a random sample of indexes and enumerate the list. A sample of values and a simple iteration would work as well.

Comment: Another small nit-pick: no need to call `list()` on your two list comprehensions; the comprehensions return lists already.

Comment: @PedroWerneck Yes, but wouldn't sample of values (rather than sample of indexes) not permit the OPs bonus request of duplicate values? (see comments).

Comment: Right. Duplicates would affect the randomness of the result if using the values. Good point.

Comment: Well, not just randomness, but you'd also be reducing the size of the result sets, i.e., `len(x) != len(set(a)) + len(set(!a))`

Answer (score 3):

Ok, there have been lots of interesting suggestions, one of which I inadvertently duplicated in a previous version of this post. But here are two solutions that have not been presented in this *exact* form:

```
def random_split(seq, n):
    indices = set(random.sample(range(len(seq)), n))
    left_right = ([], [])
    for n, x in enumerate(seq):
        left_right[n not in indices].append(x)
    return left_right
```

This does just one pass through the list and produces a uniformly random partition of the list, maintaining order. It's a refinement of hexparrot's suggestion, which was the one I inadvertently duplicated. You could use the ternary operator and two separate lists, but this seems a tad cleaner to me. Using `enumerate` allows this to handle non-hashable items, as well as sequences with duplicates.

```
def random_split(seq, n):
    rnd_bools = random.sample((0,) * n + (1,) * (len(seq) - n), len(seq))
    left_right = ([], [])
    for b, x in zip(rnd_bools, seq):
        left_right[b].append(x)
    return left_right
```

This one feels *right* to me. It's a refinement of Jacob Eggers second edit to the question. It's not very different, but instead of shuffling a list of lists, it shuffles a list of bools. I think it's a tad more comprehensible at first glance. It avoids the 2-line shuffle by using `random.sample`, which generates a copy; some may prefer the 2-line shuffle, and it's easily replaced.

Note that both of these work on the same basic principle: generate a sequence of bools and use them to index a `left_right` tuple; the first could easily be made almost identical to the second by pre-generating the boolean list.

Finally, the second solution can be converted into a *profoundly ugly* "one-liner" that I do not recommend -- obviously -- but that I display here for your amusement and ridicule:

```
random_split = lambda seq, n: reduce(lambda a, b: (a[0] + ([b[1]] if not b[0] else []), a[1] + ([b[1]] if b[0] else [])), zip(random.sample((0,) * n + (1,) * (len(seq) - n), len(seq)), seq), ([], []))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a transcript you can turn into a function:

```
>>> a = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
>>> keep = sorted(random.sample(range(len(a)),3))
>>> keep
[0, 3, 4]
>>> ([a[i] for i in keep], [a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if i not in keep])
([10, 40, 50], [20, 30, 60])
```

Comment: That doesn't keep original order.

Comment: He also doesn't want to do sample and sorting. :)

Answer (score 1):

A variation on the shuffle-sort theme...

```
def random_split(L, size):
    index = range(len(L))
    random.shuffle(index)
    return ([L[i] for i in sorted(index[:size])],
            [L[i] for i in sorted(index[size:])])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess that your random_split isn't supposed to give repeat elements.

If you don't have any duplicates in the original list, this will work <s>as a one-liner</s> as you have it in the original post, but it uses sorting.  It's a very simple, if inefficient method of doing it:

```
import random

x = ['abc', 'c', 'w', 't', '3']

def random_split(x, n):
    k = x[:]
    random.shuffle(k)
    yield sorted(k[:n], key = x.index)
    yield sorted(k[n:], key = x.index)

a, b = random_split(x, 3)
```

Example of results:

```
>>> a
['c', 'w', 't']
>>> b
['abc', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something in a few lines:

```
from random import sample
x = ['abc', 'c', 'w', 't', '3']
sample_size = len(x) // 2

sample_set = set(sample(x, sample_size))
split_list = [[x[i] for i in subset] for subset in (sorted(sample_set), sorted(set(x) - sample_set))]
```